# Create clusters of error messages in Python

Tags: python, string, k-means

I have a large set of error messages generated by hardware design simulations. There is minimal notion of grammar or language in these messages. There is no well defined syntax either. The messages may contain mathematical expressions (that raised an error in the simulation), the time when the error occurred, random symbols like @,:,[,],(,) (depending on what the design author felt like displaying!). There are spaces in the messages where they are not needed, and no spaces where they are needed.

I want to apply an algorithm to this set of messages that can group them in buckets containing similar messages, so that I can easily identify what kind of errors are showing up.

I read about finding out distances between the strings using Levenshtein distance or cosine similarity; and then using k-means clustering. I also read about word2vec and similar libraries out there. But I feel they work best on more structured english-like input data?

What would be the recommended approach for me? Of course, I will do a lot of pre-processing on the data first (like replacing all random symbols with spaces, bunching together multiple spaces into one etc.), but I will still not have meaningful words in the messages.

Comment: Definitely not word2vec but have you tried Levenshtein+k-means? There is a package and sounds like it could work: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use [dbscan algorithm from sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) with a metric of Levenshtein distance (used python-Levenshtein package).

k-means could not be used because it expects distances with respect to an origin point (Euclidean) and dbscan can take in relative distances between the items in the set to be cluster-ized.

I also did some pre-processing to extract out known strings from the error messages to clean up the messages before creating clusters.

Thanks Josep for your pointer.